# string::insert(0, "string2insert") on an empty string -- undefined behavior or valid?``

Tags: c++, string

```
int main() {
  std::string s;
  s.insert(0, "123");
}
```

I was expecting this code to give a

```
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
```

error but it compiles and runs and produces the expected result (empirically), but it's not clear to me whether this is undefined behavior or defined behavior? I don't think the documentation sheds any light on this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

Comment: inserting zero characters is a non-op, the function just returns

Comment: The only exceptions are for when you exceed the  length.  You can't give it a negative value since the parameter type is unsigned.

Comment: Could you explain your expectation?

Comment: Doesn't even compile for me.  Missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: It’s okay to insert at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation is wrong. The referenced manual clearly describes the exceptions:

> Throws `std::out_of_range` if `index > size()`.

`s.insert(0, "123")` with the `index` being 0 and `s.size()` being 0 does not meet that condition above.